# saving the database onto a file in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, bluetooth

I am working on this project where i have to save some text, picture, video or a soundclip to the database which should have the capability of being sent to others by bluetooth.

I know how to create a data base with the text and tables.

1. How do i add a photo, or a video, or a sound clip to the database. is it by adding the address of the file?
2. where is the database created/stored, by what name and what type (pardon me by i don't have much idea about SQLite)?
3. can i share the database with other android users, if yes then how?

Thanks for the help guys !!

Answer (score 2):

1. It would be better to add the path to the photo/video/sound clip. You can save the absolute path then re-create it using a File object, or save the Uri path.
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
   I would store them as a varchar since they will be string
3. What do you mean by sharing the database with other users? The actual .db file? Or the contents in the database?

Comment: i was thinking more like making a txt file out of databse and then sending it via bluetooth

Comment: Then yes, you can write a txt file using Java. You would just have to loop through the database, get the values, then write to the file in the format you want.

Comment: You can store it anywhere, in the app directory, or the phones SD cards. If you want to write to the SD card, you need the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />. Just make use the File object to create and write to the file.